# Stuck Mosfet amplifier analtsis. solving resistor values

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

Im working through some questions and am stuck on the first one. It seem so have to many unknowns in the actual question to get any result? I can find gm (conductance parameter) = 1x10^-3(A/v). and i can find a formulae relating Rin to R2 and R2. after this i am completely stuck on how to solves the values? i can only find 4 equations but have 5 unknowns?

id saturation equation 
2 KCL equations
and a resistance equation relating Rin = sum of resistances ect ( depending configuration)

Secondly because there is no cap between the signal source and the rest of the circuit when putting it in dc analysis, this makes the circuit very confusing. Suggesting that the gate always has a DC bias voltage of Zero? although because Id is given gm could be solved for and also VGS could be solved.

Also without VDD given how are you ever able to tell if the mosfet is it saturation, triode or cut off?

Is there anything i am missing?

Ive attached image of question and my working

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For your circuit Kn = 1 mA/V^2 so to get 0.5mA of a drain current Vgs need to be equal to \$V_{GS} = \sqrt{\frac{2 I_D}{kn}} + V_T = 1.5V\$ and \$gm = \sqrt{2 kn I_D} =1mS\$

Comment: As for Rin you need to express Rin in terms of a voltage gain. Because now your expression for Rin is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the Pick up on the incorrect VGS. Yes the conductance parameter is the same as what i got.

Although how is my Rin expression worng?

Comment: You wrote Rin = R1||(R2+R3) which is not true

Comment: Is this due to R1 Also being in parallel with R4 and the dependent current source? i am very confused with this when it comes to the AC analysis.

In Sedra smith micro electronic circuits. With this same case  R1 is parallel with R4. They split them in the way i have and analyzed RIN, in the same manner i have? Could you please explain were i am wrong?

Comment: For simplicity, you can remove R1 from the circuit for now and try to solve for a small-signal Rin. Can you do it?

Comment: Im not sure how to show an image so ive uploaded what i ahve done to an image website.

there was still to many unknown variable to get anywere

https://ibb.co/i1GUYc

Comment: So i ignored R1 like you said. then drew the circuit. then attempted to do thevenin analysis on the circuit from the Rin location. using mesh analysis to try to solve unknowns. Plan was to try solve unknown R values, then apply a current source to thevenin terminals a and b and get the Rthevenin value? . I was un success full due to to many unknowns.

Comment: At first, all you need is an expression for Rin in symbolic form.

Comment: And do you know the Vdd value?

Comment: No Vdd value is given.

Comment: But without Vdd I do not see how it can be solved. From where do you got this problem?

Comment: For exampel for Vdd = 10V I manage to get R1 = 1.33Meg amd R2 = 267k and $$Rin = \frac {R_1 (R_2 R_3 + g_m (R_2 + R_3))}{R_2 R_3 + g_m (R_1 + R_2 + R_3)} = \frac{1330*(267*2+1*(267+2))}{267*2+1(1330 + 267 +2)} = 500.7\textrm{k}\Omega $$ where all resistors are in k ohm's and gm is in milisiemens

Comment: The question is one if which my uni lectured made. I believe it is quite common for his stuff to not allways be solveable? God knows the logic. Thanks for your help. Ill review you working later. Having a break right now.